# Open Graph Image on Drupal 7

Tags: image, share

I was reluctant to ask this question here as it may not necessarily be a code issue, then again it must, I have a website on Drupal 7 although the framework should be irrelevant but when posting a a page to facebook, the og image gets picked up in the preview but then lost and replaced for the site logo when published.

I have configured this with the correct meta tags and are using https but still the og image never gets added to the post once published.

The specified image is displayed on the target page, here is the header code

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Jungle Drum and Bass" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/interview/jdnb-interview-annix" />
<meta property="og:title" content="JDNB Interview - Annix" />
<meta property="og:description" content="JDNB Interview - Annix" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2020-07-31T07:48:34+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/sites/default/files/ANNIX%20INTERVIEW_2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/sites/default/files/ANNIX%20INTERVIEW_2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/sites/default/files/ANNIX%20INTERVIEW_2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```

I have run the url(https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/interview/jdnb-interview-annix) through the facebook share debugger and it returned the following errors;

> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
> provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Missing
> Properties The following required properties are missing: og:url,
> og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Yet clearly in the source code snippet these tags can be seen. Also on the same debugger page there is the following:

og:url  https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/interview/jdnb-interview-annix
og:title    JDNB Interview - Annix | Jungle Drum and Bass
og:image    https://jungledrumandbass.co.uk/sites/default/files/ANNIX%20INTERVIEW_2.jpg
og:description  JDNB Interview - Annix

So facebook must be seeing it so why the warning, can anybody assist? I have tried the FB devs forum first but no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that facebook didn't like the default Drupal7 DTD, updated it to html5 version and now it all works perfectly!